# Запрет разрыва страницы между заголовком и текстом при печати (CSS)

Tags: html, css, print

Всем привет! Делаю CSS стили для печати. Хочу чтобы заголовок и идущий за ним абзац текста всегда были на одной странице. В CSS прописываю следующие правила:

```
h2 + p {
  page-break-before: avoid;
}
```

Через контекстное меню браузера вывожу страницу на печать. Желаемого результата нет. Если места не хватает, заголовок остаётся внизу одной страницы, а текст переносится на другую.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Перенос может быть не только между элементами, но и внутри, поэтому стоит добавить запрет переноса в `page-break-inside`. В принципе можно перестраховаться и добавить ещё запрет переноса после заголовка.

```
h2 {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after: avoid;
}

h2 + p {
  page-break-before: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Ну и ещё надо убедиться, что там `display: contents` не используется - пока тренировался на комментариях ruSO, на эти грабли наступил...

Comment: Не хочет. Попробовал даже применить эти стили на чистый html. Без результата :( Для доп. проверки добавил в h2 + p { color: red }, цвет отработал нормально.

Comment: @Alex, какие значения `display` у всего? Оно случайно не в таблице находится?

Comment: нет, тестировал просто повторяющиеся "h2" и "p", в body больши ничего. из css тоже ничего кроме кода выше.